# How can i add bindings to window in xaml to properties of class that jas been created as a resouse int this same window(xam)l?

Tags: wpf

I have a class that im creating in window xaml file, and after i want to bind some property of this window(im my case DialogResult property) to a property of the class that i created.

```
<Window x:Class="Galery.RegistrationWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Galery"
    Name="Reg"

    local:DialogCloser.DialogResult="{Binding Source={StaticResource UVM}, Path=DialogResult}"
    Title="Image Gallery 1.0 - Registration"
    Height="700" Width="400" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner">

<Window.Resources> 
    <local:RegisterWindowViewModel x:Key="RegViewModel"/>
    <local:RegisterValidationConverter x:Key="RegValid"/>
    <local:UsersViewModel x:Key="UVM"/>
    <local:ParameterConverter x:Key="paramConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Getting an error at 8th line
    local:DialogCloser.DialogResult="{Binding Source={StaticResource UVM}, Path=DialogResult}"

I think that happens because the class that i'm using is not created yet.

How can i add binding to my window after creating a class in Window.Resources, ro is it even possible in this way?

I hope my explanation are clear,
will be very grateful for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're having problems is because you're not using MVVM correctly. Looking at your code I assume you've realized that DialogResult cannot be bound and you've read [Joe White's article](http://blog.excastle.com/2010/07/25/mvvm-and-dialogresult-with-no-code-behind/) in which he shows how to bind DialogResult to a view model using an attached property. The real problem is that you're declaring view models in your Resources block:

```
<Window.Resources> 
    <local:RegisterWindowViewModel x:Key="RegViewModel"/> <----- BAD!
    <local:RegisterValidationConverter x:Key="RegValid"/>
    <local:UsersViewModel x:Key="UVM"/>                   <----- BAD!
    <local:ParameterConverter x:Key="paramConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

In MVVM you never do this, for reasons you've just discovered. You're supposed to create a hierarchy of view models and then bind your views to those. The resources blocks are for view-related elements only, not view models.

If you really do insist on binding Window properties to objects in your resources block then it can be done with a style setter e.g.:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MyClass x:Key="myClass"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Window.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Window}}">
        <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource myClass}, Path=MyStringProperty}" />
    </Style>
</Window.Style>
```

But again, this only works for window dependency properties, not attached properties, because the Window property you're binding to (i.e. DialogResult) doesn't support change notification so the updates aren't going to happen in the direction you want them to.